# Remove My Account top bar when user is not logged in

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

i want to remove magento top link **My Account** if user is not logged in ,i do not want to modify core files, i tried to get solution but could not find any working one .

i tried below method in : "`Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml`"

```
<customer_logout>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />
    </referenceBlock>
</customer_logout>
```

but it gives **Error** :

> Element 'customer_logout': This element is not expected. Expected is
>   one of ( attribute, block, referenceBlock, referenceContainer,
>   container, move, uiComponent ).

Comment: What is the Url of your `My account` ?

Comment: http://example.com/customer/account/ left to login

Comment: by default magento only show sign in link. once a customer log in then only it will show my account

Answer (score 1):

There is no `customer_logout` layout handle in M2, so **You can't** do with **xml**, there is no more `customer_logged_in`, `customer_logged_out` like M1

**Solution1:** It's depends to your theme, try to enable the `path hints`, and find if you find the phtml who display "**My Account**" Then add `if($block->customerLoggedIn())` condition arround that link.

**Solution2:** If your link is added via Xml, you have to create an observer with `layout_load_before` event, then you can add `$layout->addHandle('customer_logged_in')` something like:

```
$layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_logged_in');
} else {
    $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_logged_out');
}
```

Check [this](http://frankclark.xyz/modules/magento-2-get-customer_logged_in-and-customer_logged_out-layout-handles) link, you have a full solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it via layout instead you have to do it with knockout js / phtml file . Edit your theme **header.phtml** file in **Magento_Theme/templates/html** folder and add condition like this :

```
<li data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
<!-- ko if: customer().firstname  -->
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/'); ?>" style="display:none;" data-bind="style: {display:'inline'}">
    <span class="icon-account"><i>My Account</i></span></a>
</a>
<!-- /ko -->

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
"*": {
  "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
    "components": {
      "customer": {
        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
</script>
</li>
```

Comment: in header.html i see <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("top.links"); ?> where is path to edit top links file